# Does creating temp heap variables in an operator overloads when returning a new instance cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, overloading, heap-memory, stack-memory

For example, imagine a `+` operator overload to concatenate two strings;  in this example, the names of two cheeses. Here I use a `tmp` variable created on the heap. Does this cause a memory leak when the method exits?

```
Class Cheese {
private:
    int nameLen; // Length of name
    char * name; // C string
public:
    Cheese(char * str); // Constructor
    int getNameLen(); // Returns length of name
    char * getName(); // Returns name
}
```

}

```
Cheese Cheese::operator + (const Cheese & rhs) {
    char * tmp = new char[nameLen + rhs.getNameLen()];
    strcpy(tmp, name); 
    strcat(tmp, rhs.getName());
    return Cheese(tmp); // Is this a problem? Where does tmp get deleted?
}
```

Usage:

```
Cheese c1("mozzarella");
Cheese c2("provolone");
printf("Cheese Blend: %s", (c1 + c2).getName());
```

So, the return value creates another instance of `Cheese`. My concern is whether `tmp`, created on the heap, creates a memory leak. It is never deleted, and since I am including it as part of my `return` statement, I don't know where I should delete it.

Is this a legitimate concern?  Do I need this tmp variable, or can I be clever and not use it at all? Is it best practice to just put it on the stack, as follows? What's the best practice?

```
char * tmp[len + rhs.getLen()];
```

Thx!

Comment: it depends what your `Cheese` constructor is doing. If it takes ownership of the `tmp` pointer then you are fine (just remember to `free` it in `Cheese` destructor). If it makes a copy of the string then you do have a leak.

Comment: Addition to simpel01: And as your Cheese constructor cannot know whether to take ownership or not, it is most likely that you have created a memory leak that way.

Comment: Best practice is not to use raw pointers at all, but smart pointers instead. It's very likely your stuff is going to leak.

Comment: Given the members of the class and the absence of a destructor, it most probably is not fine. I'd say it most definitely leaks if given a dynamically allocated string pointer.

Comment: Another problem is that the call to `strcat` will likely create a string of length `nameLen + rhs.getNameLen() + 1` and cause a buffer overflow. **Please** use `std::string` instead!

Answer (score 0):

```
return Cheese(tmp); // Is this a problem? Where does tmp get deleted?
```

It is a problem if the constructor of `Cheese` makes a copy of the input argument.

You can use a smart pointer to delete the memory used by `tmp` when the function returns.

```
int len = nameLen + rhs.getNameLen() + 1; // Need the +1 for the null terminator
std::unique_ptr<char, std::default_delete<char[]>> tmp(new char[len]);
strcpy(tmp.get(), name); 
strcat(tmp.get(), rhs.getName());
return Cheese(tmp.get());
```

You can do away with these unnecessary complexity in your code if you use  `std::string` for type of the member variable `name` instead of `char*`. If you do that, you can get rid of the `nameLen` member variable. Then, the above function can be simplified to:

```
Cheese Cheese::operator + (const Cheese & rhs) {
    return Cheese(this->name + rhs.name);
}
```

Comment: And if `Cheese` makes no copy then it still is a problem, because it now points to freed memory.

Comment: @melak47, my answer does not apply if the constructor does not make a copy of the input argument.